# Error in running "SpringApplication.run(CataServiceApplication.class, args);" eclipse

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

trying to run my first spring application am facing this error with the line 
        SpringApplication.run(CataServiceApplication.class, args);
in main class
the error showing was The type org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files and am unable to solve can someone help me plzzz

[image]

Comment: delete you maven local repo , clean and build again

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question with it.

Comment: i deleted maven local rep which was here "C:\Users\Rania\workspace\cata_service\target\classes" and then clean & build but still the same error with one quick fix available configure build path ..

Answer (score -1):

The sollution for such a problem is to change the IDE actually now am using eclipse oxygéne and it's all right .. Try a new IDE